# Assigning a UUID on creation of a node on a neo4j powered iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, neo4j, cypher

Currently I'm developing a iOS application with a Neo4j server in my PC which should keep track of millions of unique objects. When i send the POST query to create the node with a request, the server should assign a UUID to the object, and if it already exists try again. I imagine this could be done designing a function like timestamp() but I don't know how to start programming the database. Can someone explain how to start since after this I would like to keep on making more functions to facilitate the use of the db. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've previously created a unmanaged extension for Neo4j that assigns UUIDs for any new node and makes sure that you cannot modify it afterwards, check out https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4j-uuid.

Comment: Is your extension compatible with neo4j 2.0? Since it is a ios app the only way i can contact the server is through http request with cypher, is it possible to call the property node.uuid or create a new one with uuid() function

Comment: Did not yet test for 2.0 compliance. you can access the generated property using `node.uuid`. A `uuid()` function is not available.

Comment: But feel free to raise an github issue for a uuid() function in Cypher.

Comment: Stefan, please, take a look at my question about the similar extension. May be you will be able to help.

Comment: the uuid plugin mentioned above is no longer maintained. But there's a great replacement: https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid